# Get Parent based on string value and all its children with Entity Framework Core

Tags: linq, entity-framework-core

I'm currently getting an object based on a string property like this:

```
return DbContext.Products.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Route == route);
```

This is working correctly but I now need to get its child objects (Benefits) that are related in the model like this:

```
public IList<Benefit> Benefits { get; set; }
```

How can I get this product and all its child benefits?

Something like this, but this doesn't work:

```
return DbContext.Products.Include("Benefits")FirstOrDefault(p => p.Route == route);
```

Thanks

Comment: Define "doesn't work"

Comment: Btw, hope you missed "." between ("Benefits") and FirstOrDefault() -> .Include("Benefits").FirstOrDefault. Hope that is a typo when writing OP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try like below:

```
return DbContext.Products.Include(x=>x.Benefits).FirstOrDefault(p => p.Route == route);
```

And in startup class:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...

    services.AddMvc()
        .AddJsonOptions(
            options => options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
        );

    ...
}
```